# How to filter posts by categories?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, filters

I have a custom post type and now I need to filter the projects according to their categories and without being directed to another page. Also I need to have  `all` category which would show all the projects. [Link](http://www.must.ee/uusmust/ad/#portfolio) to the test site. I would appreciate any help.

portfolio-type.php:

```
 <?php

 if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 270, 170, true ); // Normal post thumbnails
    add_image_size( 'screen-shot', 720, 540 ); // Full size screen
 }

 add_action('init', 'portfolio_register');  

 function portfolio_register() {
 $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Portfolio', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Portfolio Item', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'portfolio item'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Portfolio Item'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Portfolio Item'),
    'new_item' => __('New Portfolio Item'),
    'view_item' => __('View Portfolio Item'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Portfolio Items'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
); 
register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );
}

function create_portfolio_taxonomies() {
$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Categories' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Categories' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Category' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Category' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Category Name' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Categories' ),
);

$args = array(
    'hierarchical'      => true, // Set this to 'false' for non-hierarchical taxonomy (like tags)
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'categories' ),
);

register_taxonomy( 'portfolio_categories', array( 'portfolio' ), $args );
}
 add_action( 'init', 'create_portfolio_taxonomies', 0 );

?>
```

index.php:

```
        <!-- Start Portfolio Page -->

    <section id="portfolio" class="page">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">

                    <div class="title">Portfoolio</div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="sub-title visible-desktop">Tööd:</div>

                            <!-- Start Filters -->

                      <?php

                      $taxonomy = 'portfolio_categories';
                      $terms = get_terms($taxonomy); // Get all terms of a taxonomy

                      if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
                      ?>
                          <ul class="option-set" data-option-key="filter">
                            <li class="filter-icon hidden-phone">&#0065;</li>
                              <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
                                  <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>" ><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
                              <?php } ?>
                          </ul>
                      <?php endif;?>

                        <!-- End Filters -->            

                        <!-- Start Projects -->

                    <div id="posts" class="row isotope">


                      <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  

                          <?php  
                              $title= str_ireplace('"', '', trim(get_the_title()));  
                              $desc= str_ireplace('"', '', trim(get_the_content()));  
                          ?>     

                          <div class="item post item span4 isotope-item">

                            <a class="project-wrp fancybox" title="<?=$title?>" rel="lightbox[work]" href="<?php print portfolio_thumbnail_url($post->ID) ?>"><div class="profile-photo"><div class="profile-icon">&#0102;</div><?php the_post_thumbnail(array('230','170'),array('alt' => '')); ?> </div>  
                            <div class="project-name"><?php echo $title; ?></div>
                            <div class="project-client"><?php echo $desc; ?></div>
                            </a>
                          </div>  
                      <?php endwhile; endif; ?>  

                    </div>

                </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>

    <!-- End Portfolio Page -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Isotope Docs](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/filtering.html):

HTML:

```
<ul id="filters">
  <li><a href="#" data-filter="*">show all</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-filter=".metal">metal</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-filter=".transition">transition</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-filter=".alkali, .alkaline-earth">alkali and alkaline-earth</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-filter=":not(.transition)">not transition</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-filter=".metal:not(.transition)">metal but not transition</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="container">
  <div class="element transition metal">...</div>
  <div class="element post-transition metal">...</div>
  <div class="element alkali metal">...</div>
  <div class="element transition metal">...</div>
  <div class="element lanthanoid metal inner-transition">...</div> 
  <div class="element halogen nonmetal">...</div> 
  <div class="element alkaline-earth metal">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

JS Logic:

```
// cache container
var $container = $('#container');
// initialize isotope
$container.isotope({
  // options...
});

// filter items when filter link is clicked
$('#filters a').click(function(){
  var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
  return false;
});
```

It seems you missed an "data-filter" attribute on your filter links and the class to filter on inside of the class attribute of your post items
You could print the category slug in the "data-filter" attribute and print the same value on class attribute of your post items.

**UPDATE**

According to the new replies,

**index.php**

```
<!-- Taken from index.php -->

<!-- Start Filters -->
<?php
    $taxonomy = 'portfolio_categories';
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy); // Get all terms of a taxonomy

    if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :


?>


<ul class="option-set" data-option-key="filter"> 
  <li class="filter-icon hidden-phone">&#0065;</li> 
  <li><a href="#" data-option-value="*">All</a></li> 
  <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?> 
  <li><a data-option-value=".<?php echo $term->slug; ?>" href="#" ><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li> 
<?php } ?> 
</ul>
<?php endif;?>
<!-- End Filters -->

<!-- Start Portfolio items loop -->
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


<?php  
    $title= str_ireplace('"', '', trim(get_the_title()));  
    $desc= str_ireplace('"', '', trim(get_the_content()));

    /*
     * Note: get_the_terms() function, retrieves all the terms of a taxonomy, that belong to the post.
     * Return: (array|false|wp_error)
     *  1. array of terms object
     *  2. false if no terms in taxonomy
     *  3. wp_error object if the given taxonomy is an invalid one
     */

    $termsObj = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio_categories' );
    if ( $termsObj && !is_wp_error( $termsObj ) ) :
        //We need only the slug of this/these term(s) so looping through the result to grab only the slug value and store it in a new array
        $terms = array();
        foreach( $termsObj as $obj ){
            $terms[] = $obj->slug;
        }
        //Join or implode the new array to a string and then put it in the class attribute of the portoflio item
        $termsString = join( ' ', $terms);
    endif;
?>     

<div class="item post item span4 isotope-item <?php echo $termsString; ?>">
    <a class="project-wrp fancybox" title="<?=$title?>" rel="lightbox[work]" href="<?php print portfolio_thumbnail_url($post->ID) ?>">
        <div class="profile-photo"><div class="profile-icon">&#0102;</div><?php the_post_thumbnail(array('230','170'),array('alt' => '')); ?> </div>  
        <div class="project-name"><?php echo $title; ?></div>
        <div class="project-client"><?php echo $desc; ?></div>
    </a>
</div>  

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<!-- End Portofolio items loop -->
```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10018/discussion-between-martin-metsalu-and-iemanuele)